# How can i print data in reverse order using firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i have a noticeboard activity to show to the notice. Now i want to print last notice at first position. Means in reverse order.

```
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = snapshotIterator.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    //notificationCount++;
                    DataSnapshot snapshot = iterator.next();
```

Comment: If you are using FirebaseUI then [@Alex Mamo's][1] answer is best else you can create a new list with filling items in reverse order from you original list. then send it to adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) please use the following lines of code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Comment: No I am not using firebase ui... Actually my main activity have a linear layout which is the parent of custom notice layout....

Comment: In this case, add all the elements from your `snapshotIterator` to a list and use then `reverseOrder(Comparator<T> cmp)` according to the offical [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) of Collections and in the end pass it to the adapter.

Comment: Should work. What is the error? Have you declared and used the list inside the `onDataChange()` method? Because this how you need to do.

Comment: data is not being interted in list completely.

Comment: I don't understand you. Does it work if you declare and use the list inside `onDataChange()` method?

Comment: Sir this is a callback and that's why below line of this callback is being execute before the inserting all record... And hence some time no record and some time only single record is being shown... Got it sir?

Comment: Yes and that's why i suggested you to declare and use the list only inside the `onDataChange()` method. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: Happy to hear that. If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course and but what have to done? Means How i can consider it as an answer, by using new comment or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.

In this case, add all the elements from your snapshotIterator to a list and use then reverseOrder(Comparator cmp) according to the offical doc of Collections and in the end pass it to the adapter.
thanks to Mr. Alex Mamo