# How to sort the data in RecyclerView in Android based on the number of likes in a post in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[image: Firebase Structure]

How to show the contents in `RecyclerView` in Android app based on the number of likes in the post? I know how to sort the posts in ascending and descending order but I am having a problem in sorting them based on the number of likes in the post.

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to sort the posts in ascending and descending order

Then it will be very simple to order according to the number of likes. To solve this, you should add a new property to your post object named `numberOfLikes` and increment its value every time you get a new like. To get the number of likes, attach a listener on the `postId` reference and use `getChildrenCount()` method on your `DataSnapshot` object like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postIdRef = rootRef.child("Likes").child(postId);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long numberOfLikes = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(numberOfLikes));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
postIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: sir, thank you for your answer but sir after counting the likes of each post how to display the posts based on more number of likes post at first and least number of likes post at last in recycler view.

Comment: You said "I know how to sort the posts in ascending and descending order", what have you tried so far? Have you tried to use `orderByChild("numberOfLikes")`?

Comment: Sorry sir, I know how to display the contents in reverse order not ascending and descending. By ascending and descending i meant front and reverse order of data from database.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777129/how-can-i-print-data-in-reverse-order-using-firebase-in-android).

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?